# Partial classes consistency

Tags: c#, class, partial

I'm working with a MVC 3 C# application. I'm **extending the Model to a partial class, to include some data annotations...**

My concern is that I have hundreds of tables, and the project is on development phase, which means that **some partial classes that I manually created can easily become outdated if another developer or even myself change the respective Model**.. (Datatypes, Naming, etc)

**So is there anyway to guarantee that my Partial classes match correctly the EF Model?**

Another thing that would be appreciated would be something like **a partial class generator, which would pick the respective datatypes and names on the model and automatically create the partial class ..**

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "partial classes match correctly the EF Model"?

Comment: When I state EF Model I mean the conceptual entity model, where I have all my entities..  I cannot create data annotations because the designer file will be destroyed and automatically generated each time I change anything on database, so I created partial classes with the same properties .. so my concern is about having this partial classes equal to the conceptual model.. because if not it will not work.

Comment: Oh, you want to manually create EM model code *and* have generated EF model code?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean with EM model. I use the typical ADO.NET Entity Data Model, then I visually add my entities .. etc.. After that a designer.cs is created inside the model. Then I create partial classes, because this code is always regenerated and I want to have my "data annotations".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approch was using ViewModels. So I don't map directly my EF models on my views, I use those ViewModels and put all the **Data Annotation** attributes there (e.g `DisplayName`).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a design concern, if your extension classes are broken when the underlying data model is changed then i don not beleive it is the correct use of partial classes.

Comment: let me try to explain in a different way: I have a ADO.NET Entity Data Model where I add a table from my database, the next step is : Visual Studio automatically generates the designer.cs. So for this class I need to add a data annotation, then I create a partial class since I cannot change the designer.cs file.. Now everything is working, so my question is: is there anyway to automatically create the basic structure of those partials ? Since I have hundreds of tables.. And how can I be safe knowing that the main class (From the Model) can be changed, as soon as the database is changed also..

Comment: What sort of annotations are you making?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple enough, if the underlying model changes, your unit tests should fail, and it is likely your system won't compile anyway.

I don't understand what you are expecting from a partial class generator, how would it know the desired behaviour you have for your system?

Comment: Please see my reply to Ketchup above.. Thank you